# No cloudant DB credentials for bluemix dedicated

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloudant

I have created a cloudant DB in bluemix dedicated. But it didn't give me credentials. It provides me with a link to launch the admin portal, which works fine. But clearly not very useful without credentials to use with code...

Comment: Have you tried binding the service to a Cloud Foundry application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should bind the service to an application. Doing that you will be able to see the credentials in the VCAP_SERVICES environment variable. You can find its value within the application dashboard, clicking on "Environment Variables" on the left.

You will also find the credentials clicking on the "Service Credentials" button that you can find on the service instance panel (again in the application dashboard).

Answer (score 0):

Your dedicated environment may look a bit different that the public Bluemix dashboard, but when I click on the tile that shows my cloudant service, it takes me to a page with a menu on the left with the option "Service Credentials" once I choose that the window shows a button to "Add Credentials".
[image]

Comment: Yea, that is not showing up for me on dedicated... Just Manage and Service Access Authorization...